# iPhone: How do I override the back button in a Navigation Controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

In my app I have a basic Navigation Controller.  For all of my views, except one, the controller works as it should.

However, for one view in particular, I would like the 'back' button to not go back to the previous view, but to go to one I set. In particular it is going to go back 2 views and skip over one.

After doing some research I found that I can intercept the view when it disappears, so I tried to put in code to have it navigate to the page I would like:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
//i set a flag to know that the back button was pressed
if (viewPushed) {
    viewPushed = NO;   
} else {
    // Here, you know that back button was pressed
    mainMenu *mainViewController = [[mainMenu alloc] initWithNibName:@"mainMenu" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mainViewController animated:YES];
    [mainViewController release];
}
```

}

That didn't work, so does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your code, you seem to be trying to push another view controller onto the stack, rather than pop an extra item off it.

Try this as your code that does the going back two levels:

```
NSArray *vcs = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[vcs objectAtIndex:[vcs count]-3];
```

Alternatively you could totally replace the back button with a button of your own? In your viewController:

```
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(doSomething:)];

self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = item;
[item release];
```

Then you can write the doSomething: method to pop the two items off the stack, perhaps using the code I posted above.

Comment: So far that works great! Thank you for your response!! I was able to create the custom button, create the method, and build the array with the list of open views.  However, I am getting an 'uncaught exception' error when I step over the popToViewController line... I even tried this: [self.navigationController popToViewController:[vcs objectAtIndex:1]]; to no avail.  I'm researching more about the popToViewController now.

Comment: I ended up using: [self.navigationController popToViewController: [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES]; to go back the two levels .. works great so far, so thank you!

Comment: If you just want to go back to the top level, there's popToRootViewControllerAnimated: which should work.

Comment: With the code above that Back button does not get the little < arrow on its left side, correct? Does not seem ideal to me :-(

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {  
    //if true, back was pressed 
    if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self]==NSNotFound) {
             //your logic
    }   
}
```

Comment: Clean solution. Works on iOS 9. Thank you.

Comment: What If I want to check a condition before navigating back and if that condition fails. Then I want to stop it to navigate back. If you know windows or android then I want something like e.handled = true; like thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can try implementing the `UINavigationBarDelegate` delegate. When the method `-navigationBar:didPopItem:` is called, you can pop an additional item from the `UINavigationController`, and thus pop two items at once.

Comment: This is also more or less the way to override the UINavigationController popViewControllerAnimated method e.g. to confirm the navigation backwards. With the difference that you have to implement the - (BOOL)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar shouldPopItem:(UINavigationItem *)item method of UINavigationBarDelegate.

Answer (score -1):

```
 UIButton *home = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];  
UIImage *homeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];  
[home setBackgroundImage:homeImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
[home addTarget:self action:@selector(LogOut)  
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  
home.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 69, 26);  
UIBarButtonItem *button2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:home];
[[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:button2];
[button2 release];
button2 = nil;
```